# $6$ non-attacking rooks on $8\times 8$ chessboard

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways $6$ non-attacking rooks can be put on $8\times 8$ chessboard?

The problem is very common [rook polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial).
From this article I see that it can be done on:
$$6! \binom{8}{6}^2 = 564480  $$ ways.
Ok, but I tried to solve this task using theorems from my lecture and getting result:

### Facts

- Permutations of rows and cols don't change rook polynomial
- If we divide chessboard $B$ on $B_1$ and $B_2$ such as $B_1$ and $B_2$ have different coordinates of slots, then
  $$R_B(t) = R_{B_1}(t) \cdot R_{B_2}(t) $$
  So I permutated my chessboard like this:
  $$ OOOOXXXX \\
     OOOOXXXX \\
     OOOOXXXX \\
     OOOOXXXX \\
     XXXXOOOO \\
  XXXXOOOO \\XXXXOOOO \\XXXXOOOO \\$$
  and consider two cases:
- on left chessboard $(4\times 4)$ we have $3$ and on the second $3$ too.
  $$ \left(\frac{16\cdot 9 \cdot 4}{3!} \right)^2 = 9216$$
- $2 \times$ when on first chessboard we have $4$ and on the second $2$
  $$ 2 \cdot 4! \cdot \frac{16 \cdot 9}{2} = 3456 $$
  But sum of these two cases doesn't give me correct answer. Where I failed?

### Update

I have calculated rook polynomial:
$$\left(\frac{(16\cdot 9\cdot 4) t^3}{3!}+\frac{(16\cdot 9) t^2}{2!}+24 t^4+16 t+1\right)^2 = 576 t^8+4608 t^7+12672 t^6+14592 t^5+8304 t^4+2496 t^3+400 t^2+32 t+1$$
and it gives me the same answer

Comment: Do you mean "rooks"?  Though I do like the image of rocks on a chess board...

Comment: Rooks, not rocks

Comment: I'll correct the title, then...

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't noticed that, thanks @XanderHenderson

Comment: @XanderHenderson Not a chessboard (read it again :) ).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Having fun on such things maybe fine but please bear in mind that the person may not be a native speaker and may know one more language than most (monolingual) people :-)

Comment: @AnuragA They seem like natural typos (possibly even due to autocorrect). And while I found them amusing, I certainly did not do so in any way that made me think less of the OP for making them (also seeing as quite a few others missed them while editing the title. Especially the cheese was very easy to miss).

Comment: Mmm... cheese board.  Now I want charcuterie. :(

Answer (score 1):

Permuting the rows and columns does not change the answer, but given a permutation you don't have to have all the rooks in two quadrants as you show.  Also the $6!$ in the correct answer represents the number of ways to put the rooks in the squares after you have selected the squares.  Your approach puts all the rooks in one quadrant, then all the rooks in the other quadrant, so does not allow all the orders for placing rooks.

Comment: " you don't have to have all the rooks in two quadrants as you show" I don't understand - I still should put 6 rooks, so where should I put them if there not?

Comment: I took the $X$s and $O$s to say that all the rooks were on one letter, so they were restricted to two quadrants of the board, but there are solutions where there are rooks in all four quadrants.  You are correct that you can permute the rows and columns and still have a solution, but that doesn't help in counting the solutions.  More extremely, we can always permute the rows and columns to get the solution $a1,b2,c3,d4,e5,f6$.

Comment: "but there are solutions where there are rooks in all four quadrants" - hmm, ok, but I have just done permutation to avoid that situation and transform all cases to two corner quadrants, is that right?

Comment: When you permute the rows and columns all solutions are equivalent.  One way to count the solutions is to start with a single one and count the number of ways of permuting the rows and columns.  Permuting into the quadrants makes things much harder.  Given one solution you have not defined which permutation you will use to get the rooks into quadrants.  There will be a number of them.

Comment: I have calculated rook polynomial: $\left(\frac{(16\ 9\ 4) t^3}{3!}+\frac{(16\ 9) t^2}{2!}+24 t^4+16 t+1\right)^2 = 576 t^8+4608 t^7+12672 t^6+14592 t^5+8304 t^4+2496 t^3+400 t^2+32 t+1 $ and from that follows too that the answer is $12672$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as "how to put $8$ identical rooks to an $8\times 8$ chess board so that they do not attack each other".

The first rook has $8$ squares , the second rook has $7$ , the third $6$ etc.
So the answer will be $(8!)$.If the rooks are not identical , the answer is $(8!)\times (8!) =(8!)^2$

where $(8!)$ the permutations of the $8$ rooks. Do the math for $6$ rooks :)

Comment: It is not the same as placing $8$.  It certainly has some similarities.  The answer OP quotes is rather simple-you select first the six rows and six columns to contain the rooks, then you have $6$ places to put the first rook, $5$ for the second, and so on.